# Java - out.write

Tags: java, file-io

I try to write this line in a text file:

```
graph[bgcolor=white, size="9", center=1, margin="0.5, 0.5"];
```

like this:

```
out.write("graph [bgcolor=white, size="+9+", center="+1+", margin="+0.5,0.5+"];");
```

but it returns me an error at margin="+0.5,0.5+"

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe include the error that it is reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are fixed then just escape the `"` like this: `\"`.

```
out.write("graph[bgcolor=white, size=\"9\", center=1, margin=\"0.5, 0.5\"];");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to `escape` the string. It will be better to use `String.format()` method.

```
String str="Hello \"World\"";
String strOut=String.format("graph[bgcolor=white, size=\"%s\", center=%s, margin=\"%s, %s\"]",9,1,0.5,0.5);
out.write(strOut);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a comma violating syntax between your two margin doubles.

It appears that you simply wish to have the comma included in the string, which can be done like so:

```
out.write("...margin=" + 0.5 + "," + 0.5 + "];");
```

Comment: The OP wants `"` to appear in the output as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should write this as:

```
margin="+0.5 + "," + 0.5+"
```